# PHP ImageMagick Plane2Cylinder Perspective

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to change the perspective of the Plane2Cylinder distortion in ImageMagick via PHP.

To help explain what I'm looking for, I've created this graphic:

[image: Sample of perspective]

You can see that the lower part of the red block has a greater radius than the top part, as if you were viewing this from above center.

I have tried the optional center_x/y fields:

```
$label->distortImage(\Imagick::DISTORTION_PLANE2CYLINDER, [28,0,100], true);
```

With various settings between 0 and 1000 on each x and y, with zero results.

Anyone have any insights or hints?  I've search thoroughly, but can't find anything relevent.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no tilt in the ImageMagick plane2cylinder function. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#displace_cylinder where he uses a polynomial equation to apply a pseudo tilt to the cylinder. You would have to use some kind of inverse to that.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks, I'll check it out.  (Yep I realize this was awhile ago)

Comment: It will be better if you give bigger part of your code - then more people will try to help now it's only theory with one line of code and one image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after all this work trying to figure out how to do this using masks, filters, etc... the solution was actually dead simple.

I ended up just placing the main image over top of a taller transparent image (at the correct distance down from the top to create the perspective), then applying the plane2cylindar to that whole image.

So crazy I didn't see that to start.  Thanks for the thoughts and help though.

Edit - more details on how to achieve this.

[image]

```
$finalimage = new Imagick ('flowers_with_perspective.jpg'); // The final image

// a canvas with no background that sets the foundation for the perspective I want.
$canvas = new Imagick (); 
$canvas ->newImage ($width, $height+200, 'none'); // $height should be the input file size plus a bunch of extra height (200px for example).

// the image I am want in perspective (the flowers in my example)
$image = new Imagick ('flowers.jpg');
$image->setImageBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$image->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT); // make sure it's in transparent mode so when I overlay it on another image it doesn't have an odd background

// get vertical offset for $image on $canvans
$top = (($canvas->getImageHeight() - $image->getImageHeight())/2) +100; // should offset flower image 100px down from center

// apply $image to $canvas at 0px left and $top px down from top
$canvas->compositeImage ($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, $top);

// at this point we just have the normal 'flowers.jpg' but displayed 100px down from center on a larger, transparent canvas.

// now apply plane2cylendar to create perspective on entire image
$canvas->distortImage(\Imagick::DISTORTION_PLANE2CYLINDER, [26], true);

// now you would apply the canvas to $finalimage along with other filters/overlays/etc you'd need and save!
```

Comment: How about posting and input and output example.

Comment: Hi Luke, stackoverflow's primary intention is to let others, who have the same questions, find solutions by just looking it up. Helping the questioner is only a (useful, first moment) side effect. So please, be so kind to extend your answer with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are both absolutely right!  Thanks for the reminder.  I intended on coming back to update this but totally forgot.

Comment: @fmw42 Over 2 years ago but thanks to the above reminder I got around to it.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @BogisW I had fully intended on adding more information but moved on to other projects then eventually just forgot.  Thank you for the reminder.  I've added more info and code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fount solution with the DISTORTION_PLANE2CYLINDER but just as an idea that a hardcore perspective may reduce the strength of difference and maybe become also a point for further distortions for eg. Circular and Radial Distortion Methods (Arc).

[image]

plus

```
convert img.png \
-matte \
-virtual-pixel transparent \
-distort Perspective '200,0,0,0 100,700,100,700 700,700,700,700 600,0,800,0 ' \
img1.png
```

[image]

May give you desired radius on top and bottom.

Comment: Try  plan2cylinder, then make a binary mask. Then on the result of plane to cylinder apply -distort barrel. Then apply the mask to that to trim any horizontalbulging

Comment: Thanks.  This isn't quite what I was after, but I do appreciate the idea!

Answer (score 1):

## Programming solution

I solved this with the following code - works like a charm and delivers the right result. Be aware, the angle also depends on the distance of the viewer, not only on the eye level.

```
public function renderCyclinderToPlane()
{
    //http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#cylinder2plane
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($this->distortImageControl->getImagePath()));
    $points = array(
        70, //fov_angle,
        //center_x,y,
        //fov_output,
        //dest_center_x,y
    );
    $imagick->setImageBackgroundColor("#fad888");
    $imagick->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(\Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BACKGROUND);
    $imagick->distortImage(\Imagick::DISTORTION_CYLINDER2PLANE, $points, true);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo $imagick;
}
```

References / Credits go to:

- https://phpimagick.com/
- https://github.com/Imagick/ImagickDemos
- https://github.com/Imagick/ImagickDemos/blob/def2cedc27d74e9ddd4a638154651dd3924ade11/src/ImagickDemo/Imagick/distortImage.php

Also see: [How can I apply a pincushion distortion effect on a svg image (in order to read a qr code on round surface reliably)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75738639/how-can-i-apply-a-pincushion-distortion-effect-on-a-svg-image-in-order-to-read/75781613#75781613)

## Non-programming alternative

If you just want to put an qr code on a glass/jar/bottle, put it on the top or bottom.

Comment: I do recall trying this route but it would never work as intended for me - it's possible that the packages have been updated to fix the issues I was running into 2 years ago when working on it.  If this does produce the desired result it certainly is a much more elegant solution.